# Excel formula for cutting the string based on '\'

Tags: excel, formula

I need a little bit of help with excel here..Say I have this "c:\folder1\folder2\test.txt" and I would like to get the folder2 .

Like cutting the string after two '\' until another '\'.
I hope you can help me out with that.Thanks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"\",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without formulas with the Text to Column tool on the Data ribbon.

- Select the data,
- click **Data** > **Text to Columns**
- click **Delimited** and click **Next**
- click **Other** and enter a \ sign into the box, then click **Finish**